# Laurent series of $\sin \big( \frac{z}{1-z}\big )$ at $z=1.$

Tags: power-series, laurent-series

I beg you help me to solve this.

I used Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ and then placed $\dfrac{z}{1-z}$ as  $x$ but the answer is different.

[This is the answer of textbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xuU9y37J73OSjoB59Gk0EnT-QHk4WT8t/view?usp=drivesdk) AND  [this is my answer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XFuuTKJzOX8tmRMeNnH3XJN1kLCYKFf-/view?usp=drivesdk)

What am I doing wrong, is it the same thing ?
pls help any hint would be priceless

Comment: Please write the equations with MathJax. I can't even access the picture, so I can't read the pictures.

Comment: sorry i gave you accsess

Comment: You were asked to write the equations with MathJax, not to give us access to your documents.

Comment: I can not write with math jax its too long ,pls help

Comment: i even have another solution that is close to the answer ,but im not sure why this one is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have produced isn't a Laurent series. A Laurent series around $z=1$ needs to be in the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-1)^n$.

To obtain what you need we need to write
$$ \sin\big(\frac{z}{z-1}\big) = \sin\big(1+\frac{1}{z-1}) = \sin 1 \cos\frac{1}{z-1} + \cos 1 \sin\frac{1}{z-1}$$
Only then we use the Taylor series for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, obtaining
$$ \sin\big(\frac{z}{z-1}\big) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \sin 1}{(2n)!(z-1)^{2n}} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cos 1}{(2n+1)!(z-1)^{2n+1}}$$
Then we use the formulae
$$ (-1)^n\sin 1 = \sin(1+n\pi), \qquad (-1)^n\cos 1 = \sin\big(1+ \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\big)$$
to get
$$ \sin\big(\frac{z}{z-1}\big) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin \big(1+\frac{2n}{2}\pi\big)}{(2n)!(z-1)^{2n}} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin \big(1+\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi\big)}{(2n+1)!(z-1)^{2n+1}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\sin \big(1+\frac{k}{2}\pi\big)}{k!(z-1)^{k}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer everything was mixed for me now im sure about it ,you dont know how much you have helped me i was even thinking about suicide ,thank you and sorry for me being dumb

Comment: I don't want to sound disrespectful, but if having trouble with a mathematical problem causes you to consider suicide, you should seek a professional's help. Take care of yourself.